# QTreeView or QTreeWidget level

Tags: qt, user-interface

I need to show my list from heap. 
I am newbie in QT , so I have some questions .
1. What is better to use TreeView or TreeWidget ? 
2. How can I control level of selected node ?
3. What is correct way to add items to Tree*** component ?

Thx for answers in advance ?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post that might help you decide [Model-based and item-based?](http://www.qtforum.org/article/21348/model-based-and-item-based.html) .

In my opinion, if you looking for a more robust and extensible program you might be better off creating your own subclassed model and setting it up with the view.

However if you just want something that you can add a few entries too and be able to link that items index up with with whatever information you want to display, then you could use the widget and add your entries to it.

As you are a beginner, I would suggest that you go the long way around and get your model and view implemented as it would provide you with more experience and will also give you a better understanding of the model view architecture; Which in the long run will allow you to develop better applications.